# Receiving data from other application comes null in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

> I want to make my application like Instagram i can share pictures
>   directly from  my application  , like if i select any image from
>   gallery and when click on share my application shows on the list of chooser

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<activity
                android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTop"
                android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
                </intent-filter>

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Code for receiving data from intent is

```
private void initActivityState() {
        if (getIntent() != null){
            runShareActivityIntent();
        }
}
public void runShareActivityIntent(){
        Intent passIntent=getIntent();
        String action = passIntent.getAction();
        String type = passIntent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            Uri imageUri = (Uri) passIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);    
            Intent intentcall = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intentcall.putExtra(KEY_TYPE,type);
            intentcall.putExtra(KEY_VALUE,imageUri.toString());
            startActivity(intentcall);
            finish();
        }

    }
```

Now in my case when my app is in background i am able to get

```
String type = passIntent.getType();
```

> and i am able to get image uri but when my app is not running( kill app ) and i
>   select my application from chooser i get type as null

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding permissions to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in Manifeast.xml

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In your Main activity you have to receive the intent on oncreate() method.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
        else  if (type.startsWith("audio/")) {
            handleSendAudio(intent); // Handle single audio being sent
        }
    }
```

Now whenever you call the application using send. You can see the icon of your app. When you get the intent you can change according to your need.

I hope this may help you.